# PHP save zip to disk

Tags: php, file, web, upload, zip

I want to zip files uploaded by a user to a certain Location.
While the upload part works, I have no Idea how to zip the file. I am able to create a zip, but do not now how to actually save it to a disk.

Comment: The info in your question sounds a bit contradictory *I have no Idea how to zip the file. I am able to create a zip...*

Answer (score 14):

Simply pass the desired destination path to the zip when creating it:

```
$path = 'path/to/file.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open($path, ZipArchive::CREATE);
// add contents...
$zip->close();
```

Answer (score 2):

This is gonna surely help you out....These are 2 well explained examples hope it helps ..

1. http://www.9lessons.info/2012/06/creating-zip-file-with-php.html
2. http://davidwalsh.name/create-zip-php